# I can't seem to load a view from within a view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to develop a widget system for my application in CodeIgniter.  I have a database table of template columns that I loop through.  From within that loop, I then loop through a table of widgets for that column.  Once the DB info of a widget is loaded, I then need to determine which file is loaded for the current widget and add that as the body of the widget.  The loaded view file is stored in the body variable in the widget array.

The problem is that the widget contents are displayed before the main view file is loaded.  The contents of the widget need to be inside of the main view file.  What am I doing wrong?

My Controller:

```
$widget_types = $this->widget->type_array();

        foreach($columns as $column){

            $column_results[$column['column_id']] = $column;

            $widgets = $this->widget->retrieve($column['column_id']);

          foreach($widgets as $widget){

            $widgets[$widget['id']]['body'] = $this->load->view('widgets/'.$widget_types[$widget['type']]['view'], array('widget' => $widget));

          }

            $column_results[$column['column_id']]['widgets'] = $widgets;


        }

        $data['column_results'] = $column_results;

        $this->load->view('index_body', $data);
```

The widget model:

```
<?php

class Widget extends MY_Model {

    var $info = array();
    var $error = NULL;

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->error = NULL;
    }

    function get_info($widget_id){

        $this->db->from('template_widgets')->where('widget_id', $widget_id)->limit(1);
        if($query = $this->db->get()){

            if($query->num_rows() > 0){

                $widget = $query->row_array();

                $info = array(
                    'id' => $widget['widget_id'],
                    'title' => $widget['title'],
                    'column_id' => $widget['column_id'],
                    'position' => $widget['position'],
                    'options' => unserialize($widget['options']),
                    'type' => $widget['type']
                );

                $this->info = $info;

            }

        }

    }

    function retrieve($column_id){

        $widget_results = array();

        $this->db->from('template_widgets')->where('column_id', $column_id)->order_by('position', 'asc');
        if($query = $this->db->get()){

            if($query->num_rows() > 0){

                foreach($query->result_array() as $widget){

                    if(empty($widget_results[$widget['widget_id']])){

                        $this->get_info($widget['widget_id']);
                        if($this->error == NULL){

                            $widget_results[$widget['widget_id']] = $this->info;

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        return $widget_results;

    }

    function type_array($type = ''){

        $widget_types = array(
            0 => array(
                'name' => 'Category Feed',
                'view' => 'category_feed'
            ),
            1 => array(
                'name' => 'Members Feed',
                'view' => 'members_feed'
            ),
            2 => array(
                'name' => 'Events Feed',
                'view' => 'events_feed'
            ),
            3 => array(
                'name' => 'Category List',
                'view' => 'category_list'
            ),
            4 => array(
                'name' => 'Testimonials',
                'view' => 'Testimonials'
            ),
            5 => array(
                'name' => 'Events Calendar',
                'view' => 'events_calendar'
            ),
            6 => array(
                'name' => 'Content',
                'view' => 'content'
            ),
            7 => array(
                'name' => 'Statistics Feed',
                'view' => 'statistics_feed'
            )
        );

        return ($type == '') ? $widget_types : $widget_types[(int) $type];

    }

}
```

An example of a widget view file:

```
<?php

$str = '';

$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->model('member');
$members = $CI->member->result_array($widget['options']['max_results'], $widget['options']['order_column']);

foreach($members as $member){

    if($widget['options']['display_method'] == '1'){

        $str .= 
            '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    '.img(array('src' => attachment_url($member['avatar']['file_name']), 'width' => '192', 'height' => '108', 'border' => '0', 'alt' => 'Article Thumbnail', 'class' => 'img-thumbnail')).'
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h4>'.anchor('members/'.url_title($member['display_name']).'/'.$member['id'], $member['display_name']).'</h4>
                        <p>Joined on '.$member['date_joined'].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ';

    } else {

        $str .=
            '<div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                    '.img(array('src' => attachment_url($member['avatar']['file_name']), 'width' => '192', 'height' => '108', 'border' => '0', 'align' => 'left', 'alt' => 'Article Thumbnail', 'class' => 'img-thumbnail')).'
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <div class="media-heading">
                        <h4>'.anchor('articles/'.url_title($member['display_name']).'/'.$member['id'], $member['display_name']).'</h4>
                        <p>Joined on '.$member['date_joined'].'</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            ';

    }

}

echo $str;
```

The index body view file:

```
<?php

$CI =& get_instance();

$str = '
        <div class="container">
            <section id="content">
                <div class="row">
                    ';

if(count($column_results) > 0){

    foreach($column_results as $id => $column){

        $str .=     '<div class="col-md-'.$column['width'].'">
                        ';

        if(count($column['widgets']) > 0){

            foreach($column['widgets'] as $id => $widget){

                $str .= '<div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3>'.$widget['title'].'</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                '.$widget['body'].'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ';

            }

        }

        $str .= '</div>
            ';
    }

}

$str .= '</div>
    </section>
</div>
';

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you provided using the output buffer is how codeigniter would do this in the background anyway the only difference is that you're repeating the process which could have an impact on performance. The easiest solution would be to use to just have:

```
$data['inner_view'] = $this->load->view('inner_view_file', array(), TRUE);
```

The passing `TRUE` as the 3rd param tells codeigniter that you don't want to output the view file and that you want in returned as a string.

**NB**

In your view files you should be able to access `$this` instead of using `$CI = &get_instance();`

Lastly, even though there isn't that much wrong with the way you are going about creating your widgets, it might be worth looking in to using HMVC with codeigniter.

Comment: Ah ok.  I was never aware that the third parameter for the view loader even existed... lol.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

so instead of loading a view in a variable, I had to use output buffer and then load my view into the ob contents like so...

```
ob_start();
$this->load->view('inner_view_file', array());
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$data['inner_view'] = $output;
$this->load->view('outer_view_file', $data);
```

Which works perfectly.  A bit untidy, but gets the job done.